# Making unity inspector accept classes that inherit from a base class

Tags: unity, c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class that has a lot of classes inheriting from it, I want to make a script that you can drop one of these derived classes into. How do i do that?

```
abstract class thingy : UnityEngine.ScriptableObject
{
    // methods, variables, etc
}

class awsomeThing : thingy
{
    // Imagine there are more of these classes with different names...
}
```

I've managed to get the thingy class to show up but (as you can guess) you can only drag in that script in there, is there a way to get the inspector to accept the multiple `awsomeThing` classes?

Comment: Polymorphic serialization in Unity is fraught. [There are workarounds to get some aspects working the way you want](https://web.archive.org/web/20160629121406/http://www.codingjargames.com/blog/2012/11/30/advanced-unity-serialization/), but generally speaking you'll have a smoother time if you can avoid serializing polymorphic references wherever possible.

Comment: Does turning on Debug mode in the inspector work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce the problem described in this question when using types that are derived from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` as shown above.

Using the following code:

```cs
public abstract class SomeBaseClass : ScriptableObject
{
    public int baseClassInt = 5;
}
    
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="Derived.asset", menuName ="Testing/Some Derived Class")]
public class SomeDerivedClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public string derivedClassString = "foo";
}
    
public class PolymorphicTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SomeBaseClass someBaseInstance;
}
```

An instance of type `SomeDerivedClass` is accepted just fine in an inspector field of type `SomeBaseClass`:

[image]